# Indicador de auriculares conectados en web

Tags: javascript, html, html5, web

¿Cómo puedo saber si tengo unos auriculares conectados al ordenador? Mi objetivo es conseguirlo usando HTML5 + JavaScript.

En la siguiente página muestra todos los dispositivos de salida de audio, pero no hay forma de saber si el dispositivo activo se trata de auriculares o no.

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/

Lo único que quiero saber es si hay auriculares conectados con JavaScript y HTML5.

Comment: ¿cuál fué el resultado de tu pregunta del micrófono? Por favor no abandones tus preguntas, agradece las respuestas marcando la que consideres **correcta**.

Comment: No he abandonado la pregunta @MitsuG. La respuesta que me diste me gustó mucho y la probé, consiguiendo poner efectos al audio. El lunes tengo que probar a ver si ese audio modificado, me permite grabarlo y mandarlo al servidor en directo. De todos modos el lunes marcaré tu respuesta como correcta porque me fue útil, pero estoy esperando a ver si me dan otras soluciones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No existe una forma de saberlo porque la API de JavaScript para interacción con el SO es limitada. A día de hoy, solo puedes saber los dispositivos **disponibles** en el equipo, mas no los *conectados*.

El ejemplo que has puesto hace uso de la nueva API web audio que aún está en desarrollo y, lo que hace, es listar los dispositivos de audio/vídeo disponibles en el equipo.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
.then(function(devices) {
  devices.forEach(function(device) {
    // tienes acceso a:
    // device.kind
    // device.label
    // device.deviceId
  });
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, y con device.kind no se puede saber si es auricular o no?

Comment: Nop, solo te dirá `audioinput/videoinput`. Lo que sí te dice es el nombre del dispositivo, por ejemplo: `default (Built-in Microphone)`.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, una pena porque me vendría muy bien saber si el usuario está usando los auriculares o no, sin tener que preguntarselo claro.